# Sentrifugo - PHP can't display Unicode (Vietnamese) correctly

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I'm using Sentrifugo open source HRM software. When I insert Unicode text data, the page displays it properly, except for some tables like this.

[image: improperly displayed table]

For example, this website shows it incorrecty: *Nguyá»�n Thá»� HÃ Linh*, but when I point at that to show the title or click *View detail*, the text displays it correctly: *Nguyễn Thị Hà Linh*.

The database also changes to utf8.

Answer (score 0):

I appended two lines above in to application.ini.

I also use SET NAME UTF 8:

**$mysqlPDO = new PDO('mysql:host='.SENTRIFUGO_HOST.';dbname='.SENTRIFUGO_DBNAME.'',SENTRIFUGO_USERNAME, SENTRIFUGO_PASSWORD,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$mysqlPDO->exec("set names utf8");**

All columns in every table are utf8.

Please see these images:

[- Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2x16.png)

- [Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ix2a.png)
- [Somewhere on web show well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzSzz.png)
- [Somewhere show symbol (like ASCII)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpwQE.png)